# How to use onWindowFocusChanged() method in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have a list of objects that will be saved locally as a .json file. The problem is that I don't want to update the .json file on each user modification of one of the lists' objects. Any window focus change will be sufficient to trigger the save() function to ensure data will not be lost.

How to implement this scenario or any other suggestions?

Comment: Is the method available yet? There is an [open issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/50557) for this.

Comment: This is a serious issue, the flutter team should add a callback when window focus is changed in android!

Comment: My case was solved using WidgetsBindingObserver, I don't know if this solution will work for others' scenarios. Check it here:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WidgetsBindingObserver-class.html

Answer (score 0):

Android Side

```
class MainActivity :
        FlutterFragmentActivity(),
        EventChannel.StreamHandler {
    
      private var eventSink: EventChannel.EventSink? = null
    
       override fun configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
            super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)
            startEventChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger)
        }
    
       private fun startEventChannel(messenger: BinaryMessenger) {
            EventChannel(messenger, "Channel").setStreamHandler(this)
        }
    
      override fun onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus: Boolean) {
            super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus)
            eventSink?.success(hasFocus)
        }
    
       override fun onListen(arguments: Any?, events: EventChannel.EventSink?) {
            eventSink = events
        }
    
        override fun onCancel(arguments: Any?) {
            eventSink = null
        }
    
    }
```

Flutter Side

```
 final _eventChannel =
      const EventChannel('Channel');

  

    Future<void> getValue() async {
        try {
          _eventChannel
              .receiveBroadcastStream()
              .asyncMap((dynamic event) => event)
              .listen((event) {
            emit(state.copyWith(
              status: Status.success,
              hasFocus: event as bool,
            ));
          });
        } on PlatformException catch (e) {
          emit(state.copyWith(
            status: Status.failure,
            errorMessage: e.message ?? "Unknown error",
          ));
        }
      }
```